# stack boxes of div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stack boxes. I know how to do it if i start vertically, like starting from the top and going down. My question is, how do i do it horizontally?

[Here is how i did it vertically](http://jsfiddle.net/fum66dr4/)
[Here is how i tried doing it horizontally](http://jsfiddle.net/m6pnac2n/)
[image: Link to what i want]

```
 .box1 {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    margin-right:20px;
    border:1px solid;
    height:100px;
 }
.box2 {
    float: left;
    width:150px;
    height:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    border:1px solid;
}
.box3 {
    float: left;
    width:150px;
    margin-right:20px;
    border:1px solid;
    height:200px;
}
 .box4 {
    clear:both;
    float: left;
    width:150px;
    margin-right:20px;
    border:1px solid;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. I thought this would be possible with only html and css. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understood what you mean. This is a rough attempt. You can use positioning and z-index to achieve the result.

```
position: absolute;
top:10px;
z-index:1;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/78qptee4/

As an aside, you may find this useful:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Answer (score -1):

Using `display: inline-block` you can place multiple divs on one line.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/53vLb337/)

Comment: now, its the same as how i tried doing it horizontally. i dont want the boxes on line 2 start at the same place, but where the box on line on ends (like on how i did it vertically).